# Why doesn't the potential energy of any object equal 0

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

Consider a particle on the ground. This particle is raised by a force of magnitude $mg$ to a height $h$ above the ground. At this point, the work done on the particle by the force is $mgh$, which is equal to the potential energy of the particle. But, during this period, the force of gravity also acts on the particle and is displaced by $h$, and so does a work of $-mgh$ on the particle. Shouldn't  the two cancel and no net work should be done on the particle?

If they don't cancel, then where did the energy that came from the work done by the force of gravity go?

Comment: Note that work is a scalar quantity. Will vector addition laws apply? :)

Comment: Note that the definition of work $W=\int_{\gamma} {\bf F}\cdot\mathrm{d}{\bf r}$ depends on which force ${\bf F}$ it refers to, e.g. gravitational force, friction force, net force, etc. Gravitational potential energy by definition only refers to the work of the gravitational force, and not any other force.

Comment: @Qmechanic: Could you elaborate?

Comment: @mikhailcazi: I don't believe I used vector addition.

Comment: @Gerard your reasoning that one force produces a work in a certain direction and another opposite force produces an *opposite* work, causing them to cancel, is kind of vector addition, isn't it? Plus, QMechanic's right. The work is separate for each force, it isn't really add-able. :/

Comment: @mikhailcazi: But then why do we add the work done when friction (as an example) is involved. For example, if I push a block on a surface with a force $F$ for a distance $S$, with a force of friction $f$, the energy possessed by the body at the end is given by $FS - fS$.

Comment: The **change in energy** is calculated by doing that; it's not really net work. If you remember the work-energy-theorem: $W_{conservative} + W_{non-conservative} + W_{other} = \Delta K.E.$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think about the work-kinetic energy theorem, which states that the net work done on an object is equal to its change in kinetic energy:
$$W_{net}=\Delta\mathrm{KE}.$$

You are right that when lifting an object of mass $m$ by a height $h,$ in a uniform gravitational field, the work you do is $W_{you}=mgh$ (assuming, as you said, that you're applying a force of $mg$), and for that same displacement, the work done by gravity is $W_{grav}=-mgh.$ The fact that these two cancel out ($W_{net}=W_{you}+W_{grav}=0$) means that the change in  kinetic energy of the object after being lifted is $0$. So the work done by gravity went to sucking energy out of the object that you were adding, thereby converting it to gravitational potential energy. (If it did not get sucked out, then the object would gain kinetic energy--just imagine a case where you apply the same force to the object as you did when you lifted it, but this time there is no gravitational field. Then, since there will be a net force on the object in that case (or, net work will be done (by you)), the object's KE will increase.) Meanwhile, the change in gravitational potential energy of the object is $\Delta U = -W_{grav}$.

So, to summarize, you do positive work on the object by lifting it. Normally, that work would cause the KE of the object to increase. In this case, though, we have gravity doing negative work simultaneously, so the work you're doing is getting converted to potential energy by gravity. No net work is done, so the object has no KE after being lifted.

Comment: Excellent answer. Just to clarify, What is the exact definition of a 'field' (magnetic fields, gravitational fields, etc.)? If we push an object on a rough surface, the frictional force does negative work, sucking kinetic energy out. But it also produces heat, which gravity does not. I'm guessing this is because the object gains potential energy. But when does this potential energy exactly come into existence?

Comment: A field (in physics) is a quantity with a value at each point in space. You can have a vector field, a temperature (scalar) field, etc. The connection between a field and a potential energy is that fields associated with conservative forces may be written as the gradient of some physical quantity (e.g. grav. potential), and if you do a line integral in these fields (e.g. calculate work done), the result depends only on the start and endpoints. Gravitational fields are conservative, while magnetic fields are not, for instance. Work done by friction is path-dependent, so it's not conservative.

Comment: So magnetic fields are not conservative because they can't be written as a gradient, right? They have different shapes altogether.

Comment: You can define a potential energy for conservative forces/fields, but not for non-conservative forces like friction. So in the case of a (conservative) gravitational field, the potential energy comes into existence by the fact that gravity is a conservative force/vector field (so the potential energy is defined). Whenever the conservative field does +/- work on an object, the potential energy of that object changes. When a non-conservative force like friction does work, that energy goes to heat, as you said in the comment above.

Comment: That's right, magnetic fields can't be written as a gradient. They can be written as a curl instead.

Comment: @MikeBell A statement like “Meanwhile, the change on gravitational potential energy is $\\Delta U = - W_{\rn grav}$” can be misleading in that the object by itself cannot be a store of gravitational potential energy. You need to have the Earth and the object as the system.